# 7+7 clean animals(Noach 7:2)

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, animals, parashat-noach

Why is the clean animals mentioned only once and the rest of animals(a pair) is mentioned numerous times with the omission of the clean .

Comment: This is an excellent example of a question that the addition of a quotation or two would improve.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1715/603

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22347/inconsistency-in-listing-creeping-things-in-noachs-arks-population